# Strange HTTPS browser behavior when C# methos is returning a file

Tags: c#, api, rest, ssl, tls1.2

I’ve an application (C# on .NET Framework) with one method which returns a file.
This method handles a http get request in a web api controller.
A certificate TLS v1.2 is deployed and it’s working fine too. I can use the application and the browser says that the site is secure. Great!

I’m encountering a problem and that only when I would download the file using a browser. This method works well, the file is returned and correctly saved on the client side.

Nevertheless, just after the file is downloaded the browser tells that the site isn’t sure due the certificate is not available.
Client side, I’ve tried 3 different browsers:

- Chrome
- Edge
- IE

Server side, I’ve tried a lot of different kind to returns a file:

- WebApi so ApiController class
- MVC so Controller class
- HttpResponseMessage
- ActionResult
- FileContent

This browser’s behavior remains and I finished all my ideas.

Someone would help me to understing what’s happening?
Have a nice day

Comment: Could you include (in your question) the exact error/message that you get.

Comment: is there any redirect in your application? for instance, are you serving the files over HTTP and you have a redirect to use HTTPS for the whole application?

Comment: I've not any error, I've just a warning showed in the broswer saying that the site isn't sure.  I've none redirection in whole application and I've serving files by a method in in class. This behavior is amazing strange.